# Why such a strange plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I don't understand the problem with the plot I made; `x values` are supposed to go up to `46134` and `y values` are supposed to go up to `7094`... On the plot, `x values` go to nearly `150000` and `y values` to `20000` ...!

And why are points joined in such a strange manner?

Code I used:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.DataFrame(
         [
             ["Albania",   28,   726],
             ["Armenia",   28,  1746],
             ["Austria",  543, 15307],
             ["Belgium", 7094, 46134]
         ],
         columns = [
             "Country",
             "y",
             "x"
         ]
    )
data

plt.plot(x, y, 'o-', color='red')
```

Plot:
[image]

Comment: Where do your x and y variables come from?.

Comment: Did you mean: `plt.plot(data.x, data.y, 'o-', color='red')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`plt.plot(x, y, 'o-', color='red')` should throw an error unless you have defined the variables `x` and `y` somewhere else in the program.

Your x and y variables happen to hold numerical information that was able to be plotted, but since you wanted to plot the 'x' and 'y' columns from your dataframe, you probably meant to write:

`plt.plot(data['x'], data['y'], 'o-', color='red')`

Comment: Yes @Derek, this works. I made a confusion between `x` as a variable and `x` as a . column name. Sorry for this lack of attention. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked! If it helped, please consider accepting the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers